# Detect if a view is loading because back button was pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to detect if a view is appearing because back button was pressed. For example with this hierarchy, `VC1 -> webViewController -> VC3`, if in `VC3` i press the back button I want to detect that when `webViewController` appears. My goal is to use this in the `shouldStartLoadWith` method to avoid refreshing the page when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in `webViewController`

```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
     {
        //This Check is for if still webview is Loading the page or content
        if (webView.isLoading) {
        NSLog(@"your webview is still loading");
        return;
}
    else {
        //this is for when its finish loading
        NSLog(@"your webview is loaded completely");
}
     }
```

Comment: How is this supposed to inform me if  the back button was pressed or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closure` for such callbacks.

**Example**:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! VC3
        controller.completionHandler = {
            //Code to execute after back button is pressed.
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC3: UIViewController
{
    var completionHandler : (()->())?

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.index(of: self) == nil
        {
            //Back Button pressed
            self.completionHandler?()
        }
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
}
```